# Getting a "404" when trying to send a request to a RESTful API

Tags: python, rest, flask, oauth-2.0, restful-authentication

I'm attempting to create a Flask application in Python that communicates with a RESTful API that uses OAuth2.0, but I'm having trouble sending requests. I'm successfully getting an access token from the server, but when I try to make a GET or POST request, I always get a 404 as a response. I'm new to RESTful API's so I don't know what I could possibly be doing wrong here or what a 404 means in this context.

Here is the .py file where I attempt to send a GET and POST request to the API. `TokenHandler` is just a helper class I made that keeps track of token related info, and the `print(response)` lines always print "Response [404]".

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect
from src.apitest import TokenHandler
import requests
from oauthlib.oauth2 import LegacyApplicationClient
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

token_handler = TokenHandler()


@app.route('/find_customer')
def find_customer():
    return render_template('customer_find_page.html')


@app.route('/find_customer', methods=['POST'])
def find_customer_get():
    customer_id = request.form['text0']
    oauth = OAuth2Session(client=LegacyApplicationClient(client_id=token_handler.CLIENT_ID))
    oauth.fetch_token(token_url=token_handler.TOKEN_ENDPOINT,
                      username=token_handler.USERNAME, password=token_handler.PASSWORD, client_id=token_handler.CLIENT_ID,
                      client_secret=token_handler.CLIENT_SECRET,
                      scope=token_handler.SCOPE)
    response = oauth.get("https://sedonacloudtest.com/api/customers/"+customer_id)
    print(response)
    return redirect('/find_customer')


@app.route('/add_customer')
def add_customer():
    return render_template('customer_add_page.html')


@app.route('/add_customer', methods=['POST'])
def add_customer_post():
    customer_id = request.form['text0']
    customer_name = request.form['text1']
    data = {"customer_id": customer_id, "customer_name": customer_name}
    oauth = OAuth2Session(client=LegacyApplicationClient(client_id=token_handler.CLIENT_ID))
    oauth.fetch_token(token_url=token_handler.TOKEN_ENDPOINT,
                      username=token_handler.USERNAME, password=token_handler.PASSWORD, client_id=token_handler.CLIENT_ID,
                      client_secret=token_handler.CLIENT_SECRET,
                      scope=token_handler.SCOPE)
    response = oauth.post("https://sedonacloudtest.com/api/customers", data=data)
    print(response)
    return redirect('/add_customer')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: Have you tried to `get` that resource using something else to make sure it's there? 404 means the resource is not at the place you're looking for it, it's not a problem with the code itself but rather the path you're using.

Comment: As to "what 404 means in this context" - it's standarised what most response codes mean: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: @h4z3 What if it's a ```post```? Why would a ```post``` return a 404? The point of a ```post``` is adding a resource to the server, so why would it need to check if something is there?

Comment: Nah, you're confusing resource and data. Think of the resource url you're using as a function (because on the server-side, they are functions, you just access them via url). Post is basically passing a value to a function but the function needs to be there. 404 means "dude, I don't know what you want me to do, there's nothing with this url" ;)

Comment: That's what the decorators `@app.route` do - they bind the url and a function together. I thought you're trying to add your own api on top of an existing one (`oauth.get`), but seeing your replies, it seems you're trying to access your own api inside itself?

Comment: I haven't worked with rest in python, so I won't help you with the code (I just separately know about python and about rest), but you basically need a server (flask without calling oauth) that serves your resources (from database, files, whatever you want) AND a client app (oauth part) that gets the data. ;)